# Data Studio, Report Level not working for Date Range Control

Tags: report, looker-studio, date-range

My Date Range Control works fine at page level but doesn't work at report level.
I don't have this problem with Drop down at report level.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. Turned out that page settings had a custom data range. Go to Page > Current page settings > and change the Default date range to "Auto".

page setting > default date range:

[image: page setting > default date range]